# How to fix sketchware pro fcm notification sdk 34 Error

Tags: request, sketchware

I am new beginninger Sketchware DEV.
I have only android phone. I only use Sketchware pro. And how to fix Sketchware message service build in lib 19.0.0 to update version and another ways sir . Please help me

Comment: Greetings to Stack Overflow, a hub for exceptional specialists, though regrettably not sorcerers. To aid in facilitating effective assistance, I recommend familiarizing yourself with our guidelines on creating minimal reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example